# How is it possible to have different input image sizes in Detectron2?

Tags: computer-vision, detectron, mask-rcnn

I am using Detectron2 (Mask-RCNN Model) and passed by:

```
_C.INPUT.MIN_SIZE_TEST = (800, 832, 864, 896)
_C.INPUT.MAX_SIZE_TEST = 1333
```

How is it possible to have different input image sizes?
How are they entered into the model and Shouldn't the model have a consistent input size?

I tried to check the documentation but didnt find a clear answer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

With a given kernel size and stride, Convolutional layers can process any input size and return the feature map with corresponding output dimensions.

The subsequent FCs do require a fixed input vector. This is where the Mask-RCNN uses RoI (Region of Interest) align that converts the region proposal to a fixed size for subsequent processing by the network. It has the same goals as RoI pool in a Fast-RCNN model.

Hope this explains why the input size need not be fixed.

Comment: Your answer makes sense, so Mask R-CNN can handle different input sizes.  So then what is the purpose of the Detectron2 MIN_SIZE_TEST & MAX_SIZE_TEST?

Comment: While the models in detectron2 can handle different input sizes, it still allows you to specify the minimum size of image (and the maximum) that you want to pass to the model. So for instance when you specify the MIN_SIZE_TEST, it ensures that the shortest side of an image during testing meets this value. If it happens to be smaller, the image is resized.